# Automatically opening completion window in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

I am new to Eclipse and I want to know if it's possible to have the completion window open up automatically while I type (Visual Studio style) and not by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto code completion on Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202223/auto-code-completion-on-eclipse)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It is possible. You can simply write: `.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` in `Auto activation triggers for Java` field, under `Preferences` > `Java` > `Editor` > `Content Assist`.

While writing Java code, after the dot `.` the window opens automatically after a configurable amount of time (default is 200 ms.)

In general, what you can do is add an auto activation trigger, for example `_`, so when you want the windows to popup, you type and delete that character (althought I don't think that's better than `CTRL` + `SPACE`).

Comment: You could theoretically add a trigger for every character I guess.

Comment: dont forget to add < so you get it in the .xml files to

Comment: but this only for eclipse with java, i want it should be also in eclipse java-script there is only allowed to add 4 latter's, any idea?

Comment: You can manually set the value for javascript(jsdt):  .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.prefs, content_assist_autoactivation_triggers_java=._abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

Comment: is backspace a character I can add?

Comment: @majgis It seems like the location for the JavaScript content assist triggers has changed. Do you know where it is in Juno?