# Auto Complete activates after 2 characters Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete

Is there anyway to make Eclipse activate autocomplete after I type 2 characters without a space, sort of like Flash Develop?

Also is there a way to turn off variable name suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I had the same doubt! I solved it.. here at this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202223/auto-code-completion-on-eclipse#answer-6203060][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202223/auto-code-completion-on-eclipse#answer-6203060

Answer (score -1):

What type of code are you autocompleting?  If you go to Window -> Preferences in Eclipse and filter by Content Assist, you can get to the preferences that you can change for your autocompletion.  The options available depend on which Eclipse editor you're using though.  Also, hitting `Ctrl + Space` at any time should activate autocompletion.