# Keep Eclipse from confirming auto completions on "space", "(", "<", etc

Tags: eclipse

As described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202223/auto-code-completion-on-eclipse) one can have auto complete (Content Assist) appear automatically as you type. There is, however, a problem with this setup.

Eclipse figures it's a good idea to **accept** the first suggested completion when LOADS of different keys are pressed. Such as space, braces and other stuff you really need to type often without inserting a suggestion.

Any Eclipse wiz out there who knows how to turn this auto insertion off without disabling the suggestions?

Comment: Since Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10) there is a preference for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53872999/6505250

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable statement completion on space in Eclipse Content Assist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586771/disable-statement-completion-on-space-in-eclipse-content-assist)

Answer (score 1):

Open Window --> Preferences. Type "Content Assist" in the filter, and disable it for your editor (or change activation preferences).

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Editor` -> `Content Assist` -> `Auto Activation` -> `Auto activation triggers for Java` and type ".abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" . You can add or remove any characters, on pressing which the auto-complete menu gets triggered.

In your case make sure that you do not have a whitespace, ( or < included in the `Auto activation triggers for Java`