# How to make eclipse only complete the auto complete IF pressed ENTERED .. Not Dot or Space

Tags: java, eclipse

Good Day Dears ..

as far as I know i have searched for relative question but I didn't find anything.
also i am searching for an answer to this for a while over the internet but with no luck.

I am using eclipse for developing java .. I am happy with using the Auto complete features build in in eclipse  .. only one thing is bother me .. if i am writing a variable name and then Pressed Dot or Space .. the eclipse will automatically pick the first choice which is something I don't want.

the question is .. is there a way to make the auto complete take place only if ENTERED has been pressed?

Thanks guys ..

Comment: Since Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10) there is a preference for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53872999/6505250

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable statement completion on space in Eclipse Content Assist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586771/disable-statement-completion-on-space-in-eclipse-content-assist)

Answer (score 0):

Well .... I have Found an answer for myself and other ...

check this https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=348857#c12

just copy the jar far for to eclipse/dropins -folder

it should work great after you restart Eclips ..