# Eclipse autoactivation for any character -> problem: pressing spacebar triggers autocomplete

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, space

I added in eclipse > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Autoactivation triggers for Java: .abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJIKLMNOPQURSTUVWXYZ

Now I don't need to press CTRL + SPACE. It's very useful. The only BIG PROBLEM is that auto-complete gets triggered when I press SPACE.

Example: I want to declare "Random rand = ..." but Eclipse completes automatically to "Random random ...". How do I fix this problem. :(
I don't want to press CTRL + SPACE but have the feature of autoactivation all the time.

PS: Stack Overflow shows me old questions about this problem, but there is no real solution.

PS2: Is there a way of "spacing" without pressing SPACE? lol

PS3: My answer may be a duplice but the answer to the other questions are OLD and don't work for the newest version of Eclipse -.-

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53872999/6505250

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable statement completion on space in Eclipse Content Assist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586771/disable-statement-completion-on-space-in-eclipse-content-assist)

Comment: I saw all these questions and tried most of the answers. They don't fix my problem. Tell me if any answer WORKS on the current version of eclipse.

Comment: In Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10) an option has been introduced for that. [Read my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53872999/6505250) and [watch my video showing this new feature in action](https://youtu.be/aM3UUycl1rs?t=209).