# Make ADT Code Assist work like Xcode autocomplete

Tags: android, eclipse, autocomplete, adt, code-assist

Is there a way to setup ADT such that the "Code assist" / autocomplete kicks in as soon as I start typing, without having to press Ctrl + Spacebar?

Basically, I'm an iOS developer starting out with Android, and I've gotten very used to the way Xcode autocomplete kicks in as soon as you start typing.

With ADT, it seems that once I type a "object.", the code assist kicks in, but if I want to use it save time typing out class variables, I have to actually press Ctrl+Spacebar, and this gets annoying.

Comment: This is a question about Eclipse, not Android.

Comment: It's about ADT, which is a version of Eclipse just for Android...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the answer via this question: [Auto code completion on Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202223/auto-code-completion-on-eclipse)

Basically the auto activation trigger for auto-complete by default is set to only the character ".".

To make code assist / auto complete trigger always, you have to change the string to:

```
.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

In v21.x.x version of ADT, this is located in Preferences -> Java --> Editor --> Content Assist.