# Eclipse wont auto suggest inherited methods

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

In eclipse after you put the period to call a method it will show auto corrected methods as your typing.It works fine with methods in the class that are directly in that class, but if it inherited that method it doesn't. when i fully type the methods out though they still work fine. Ive messed around in the content assist settings in preferences but it didnt work. i could be doing something wrong with the content assist settings but even with default setting its not working.

exsample:
if i call jframe.setDefaultCloseOpperation() works just fine and auto suggests as i write
if i call jframe.setTitle doest though it doesnt work and i just have to write it out fully.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eclipse autocomplete not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746294/eclipse-autocomplete-not-working)