# Unable to Select Suggestion in Eclipse via Content Assist?

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, ide, content-assist

When I press + press ctrl+space, `Eclipse` shows a list of suggestions via `Content Assist`:

[image]

However, when I click on any of the suggestions, nothing happens. In other words, it doesn't actually select the suggestion I clicked on.

What might be causing this?

P.S

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56906167) deals with a case where `Content Assist` does not showing proposals at all so it is not the same as the scenario I'm describing.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, nor have I ever seen it myself or heard about it from others. Please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce your issue with current Eclipse 2022-03 and a fresh workspace (to make sure it is not caused by a plugin you have installed).

Comment: @howlger I restarted eclipse and the problem seems to have disappeared.. I don't think I could reproduce it at this point. If anyone has any idea what might have caused this "glitch" I would be interested in knowing..

Comment: Look in the error log whether there is something.