# AutoSuggestions/Intellisense not working in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, intellisense, content-assist, autocorrect

Eclipse Intellisense (CTRL+Space) is  not showing any result.

[image: EclipsError for not showing autosuggestions]

I checked the content Assist settings all the Java Related types are in checked state only.

[image: content assist settings]

I switched to IntelliJ but the same issue is there as well. Can anyone please suggest what to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eclipse autocomplete not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746294/eclipse-autocomplete-not-working)

Comment: Which editor is this? Is this a file in the workspace?

Comment: This is the general Eclipse Editor and yes it is a java file @nitind

Comment: Content assist only works for Java files which are in a Java project in the current Eclipse workspace (and opened using the Java Editor).

Comment: for my case it is not working, I am trying to use content assist for a java file which is in my Java Project in current workspace only.