# My Java autocomplete methods do not appear after putting dot or pressing ctrl+space in eclipse. Check my Eclipse Editor

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

[image: Editor]I am using Eclipse Version: 2022-06, with Jdk 1.8 (instead of default jre, which was also not working for showing java doc suggestions) I have tried all the Windows--> Preferences --> Java --> Content Assist but its not working. Please check the following Images and help.

[Eclipse Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fzfc1.png)

[image: Eclipse Settings]

[image: Eclipse Content Assist Advanced Settings]

Comment: Why do you have _Enable non-blocking completion_ disabled (does a plugin you have installed not allow it)? Which Eclipse version? Which additional plugins do you have installed? Is there anything related in the error log?

Answer (score 0):

If you're facing this issue only when trying to use autocomplete for
`System.out.println()`
Try 'sysout' instead and then press ctrl+space.

Comment: No, it appears for all kinds of classes and objects whenever I try to see the suggested options of methods after dot

Comment: ctrl+space also does not work

Comment: Try the suggestions in this link, this question has been asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746294/eclipse-autocomplete-not-working