# Java Eclipse - Simple shortcut

Tags: java, eclipse

simple question:
What is the shortcut to autocomplete 
() {
}
in Java Eclipse?

I've been searching like crazy to find what the key combination for this is.

Comment: I think your question was answered here:
[Question 6202223](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202223/auto-code-completion-on-eclipse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to the Window | Preferences dialog.
2. Select Java | Editor |
   Typing.
3. In the "Automatically Close" section on the right, switch
   on the checkboxes for everything you want automatically closed - so
   parentheses and braces.
4. Click OK.

Comment: Does it close small brackets too which the OP needs? **()** thing

Comment: Yes, there's an option for parentheses.

Comment: but this will just put closing braces and parentheses. The OP wants to automatically generate opening and closing, both the braces parentheses.

Comment: OP asked how to autocomplete the pairs.  I interpret that to mean, getting the automatic closure when you've opened them.  You've obviously interpreted OP's question differently from me, @KavishMittal - that's perfectly OK.

Comment: True. My interpretation came true what he wanted.  Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Put your mouse cursor within a class, write your method name and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. It will show you the suggestion whether you want to create new method stub (method). Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it will generate the method definition with an empty body.

Example: `hello` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> key

Output:

```
private void hello() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

This way you can generate a method stub. Works for methods to create within functions.

**However there is no existing way to just generate only "(){}" in eclipse. It's kind of copy paste thing which should forever remain copied somewhere somehow in eclipse so that you just paste it with some shortcut keys inside the eclipse IDE**

**To auto-close an opened brace or parentheses, see  Dawood ibn Kareem's answer below**

Comment: Thanks, this was kind of what I was looking for!

Comment: Give a reason for why anyone has downnvoted my answer.