# Eclipse auto api functionality

Tags: android, eclipse

Am new to android, and i have seen some videos regarding the training,

In that, i have seen like if you want to type the below code

Button B1;

In that video, that person will type "But" and it will automatically list Button class.

I don't know how to do this in my eclipse ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically opening completion window in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765054/automatically-opening-completion-window-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

After typing letter, you need to press ctrl+spacebar.. It will show you list of classes starting with that letter and you can choose one of them as per your requirement.