# Eclipse Content Assist Auto activation triggers for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, eclipse

This is with reference to this answer about Auto activation triggers for JavaScript:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4765318/1472186
The answer was only for Java.

There is a comment suggesting editting Eclipse settings file manually to bypass the 4 character limit on the trigger for JavaScript, but I could not find the settings file in my Eclipse Luna.

I have also looked at [this document](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/FAQ#Can_I_enable_code_completion_to_be_activated_as_I_type_like_how_it_works_in_Visual_Studio.3F), but it is only for Java.
I have located `\configuration\org.eclipse.core.runtime` but the files inside don't seem to be editable.
Any idea on how to add more characters into auto activation triggers for JavaScript?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can overcome that 4 character limit for JS content assist:

1. File->Export->General->Preferences and save your preferences to a file.
2. Open the file you just saved in a text editor such as notepad.
3. Find the string 
   `org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui/content_assist_autoactivation_triggers_java`
   and enter the auto activation triggers you want such as 
   `.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`
   then save the file.
4. Back in Eclipse File->Import->General->Preferences and import the file you just edited.

And that is that, you now have full content assist in JS

Comment: Mind you `content_assist_autoactivation_triggers_java` will be overwritten with `.abc` (i.e. truncated to four characters) every time you save content assist settings in Eclipse UI.