# Enable the Javascript intellisense within Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, intellisense, netsuite, javascript-intellisense

I just installed Eclipse.  I am hoping to have better intellisense for my Javascript.

I know how to turn it on.  It's Windows->Preferences->Javascript->Editor->Content Assist, and checking enable auto activation with a short delay.  But the 'triggers' only allows for four characters, which severely limits it's usefulness. (For other Content Assists, such as with Java, you can insert as many characters as you would like, as discussed in this thread:  [Improving Eclipse autocompletion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929773/improving-eclipse-autocompletion), but that isn't the case in the Javascript section)

I don't really want to have to press 'Control + Space' all the time.  Is there any way I can enable the autocomplete more fully?

Also, due to the way my projects are set up (as Netsuite Projects), I can't change the project Type, and use Tern's autocomplete or anything like that.

On looking more deeply, I may need to simply revert to an earlier version, but any other ways to perform this would be well appreciated.

EDIT:  Found my own answer (below)

Comment: I was able to find my own answer, here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30700372/eclipse-content-assist-auto-activation-triggers-for-javascript.

Comment: I have answered related question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444741/does-anyone-know-where-to-find-a-ss2-0-jsdoc-definition-library/37474111#37474111

Comment: This works for both SS1.0 and SS2.0, just make sure that you have the copy of the script file api which you can download at the left portion of the file cabinet.

Comment: This doesnt answer your question, but I def recommend you try VSCode. It is a free editor/IDE developed by Microsoft. While it supports multiple languages, it has EXCELLENT tooling support for all things Javascript.