# Eclipse for C/C++ Developers and autocomplete

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete

I'm using Eclipse for C/C++ Developers. In order to use auto-complete I have to press ctrl+space and only then Eclipse gives me a list of proposals. I want to ask how to make Eclipse show me proposals "on-the-fly", without using ctrl+space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically opening completion window in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765054/automatically-opening-completion-window-in-eclipse)

Comment: I looked at the link. It's for using Eclipse with Java. 
I have Eclipse for C/C++ Developers and when I go to Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist, I see no "Auto activation triggers" field.